# br Tag Inside ASP.NET GridView Cell Don't Break The Line

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a string that I bind into my gridview and it include a html tag inside (a simple `<br>`).
It should break the line on my site but it **didn't**.

my string is (for example):  `text text text <br> text text text` and it **show** `<br>` instead of break the line. I want it to look like this:

```
text text text
text text text
```

My Code:

```
mygrd.DataSource = GetContentAsDataTable();
mygrd.DataBind();
```

Client side:

```
<asp:GridView ID="mygrd" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Content" HeaderText="Content" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Thanks for your helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add HtmlEncode="false" or  HtmlEncode="True" on your `<asp:BoundField>` Play with both the setting and see if you get desired output.

```
   <asp:BoundField  DataField="Content" HeaderText="Content" HeaderStyle-Width="5%"  HtmlEncode="false" ItemStyle-Width="5%" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ReadOnly="true" />
```

if that does not work then.

```
Create a RowDataBound method in the codebehind
 Protected Sub mygrd_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)

If (e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow) Then

e.Row.Cells(yourcellnumber).Text = "text text text <br> text text text"

End If

End Sub
```

This should work.